# mysql: using dynamic field in match query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

having trouble with this query:

```
        SELECT contests.*, 
   ( 
          SELECT Count(*) 
          FROM   participants 
          WHERE  participants.contest_id = contests.id 
          AND    participants.active = 1 
          AND    participants.deleted = 0) AS cur_participants, 
   ( 
          SELECT path 
          FROM   media 
          WHERE  media.entity_type = 'contests' 
          AND    media.entity_id = contests.id 
          AND    deleted = 0 
          AND    type = 'img' 
          AND    is_primary = 1) AS thumbnail, 
   ( 
          SELECT description 
          FROM   ( 
                        SELECT contest_id, 
                               description, 
                               deleted 
                        FROM   rewards_assets 
                        UNION 
                        SELECT contest_id, 
                               description, 
                               deleted 
                        FROM   rewards_cars 
                        UNION 
                        SELECT contest_id, 
                               description, 
                               deleted 
                        FROM   rewards_houses) AS rewards 
          WHERE  rewards.contest_id = contests.id 
          AND    rewards.deleted = 0) AS **reward**
          , (match (name) AGAINST ('car') + match (description) AGAINST ('car') + match (**reward**) AGAINST ('car')) AS rel 
    FROM   contests 
        WHERE active = 1 AND deleted = 0 AND end_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
        HAVING rel > 0
        ORDER BY rel DESC
        LIMIT 0, 201
```

This returns:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'reward' in 'field list'
enter code here
```

It seems that the match function can't work with the reward field created with "AS".. I tried moving that match part directly to the where clause and order by clause without naimg it `rel` in the SELECT, with no luck..

how to bypass that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Bill,
Your answer was very helpful, and helped me find a workaround for this issue:

```
        SELECT contests.*, 
   ( 
          SELECT Count(*) 
          FROM   participants 
          WHERE  participants.contest_id = contests.id 
          AND    participants.active = 1 
          AND    participants.deleted = 0) AS cur_participants, 
   ( 
          SELECT path 
          FROM   media 
          WHERE  media.entity_type = 'contests' 
          AND    media.entity_id = contests.id 
          AND    deleted = 0 
          AND    type = 'img' 
          AND    is_primary = 1) AS thumbnail 
          , (match (name) AGAINST ('car') + match (description) AGAINST ('car')) AS contest_rel, ( 
          SELECT reward_rel
          FROM   ( 
                        SELECT contest_id, 
                               match(description) AGAINST('car') AS reward_rel, 
                               deleted 
                        FROM   rewards_assets 
                        UNION 
                        SELECT contest_id, 
                               match(description) AGAINST('car') AS reward_rel, 
                               deleted 
                        FROM   rewards_cars 
                        UNION 
                        SELECT contest_id, 
                               match(description) AGAINST('car') AS reward_rel, 
                               deleted 
                        FROM   rewards_houses) AS rewards 
          WHERE  rewards.contest_id = contests.id 
          AND    rewards.deleted = 0) AS reward_rel 
    FROM   contests 
        WHERE active = 1 AND deleted = 0 AND end_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
        HAVING (contest_rel+reward_rel) > 0
        ORDER BY (contest_rel+reward_rel) DESC
        LIMIT 0, 20
```

I selected the rewards rel directly inside the subquery (the field is fulltext-indexed) and then did the math outside (in having and order by) after having all the match indexes calculated separated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here:

1. You can't reference an alias in another expression in the select-list.

   ```
   SELECT 123 AS x, x+1 AS y -- WRONG

   SELECT 123 AS x ... WHERE x = 123 -- WRONG
   ```

   The workaround is to put the alias definition in a derived table.

   ```
   SELECT x, x+1 AS y FROM (SELECT 123 AS x) AS t
   ```
2. `MATCH()` only works on real columns, for which a FULLTEXT index has been defined. You can't reference any kind of alias or derived column in MATCH(). So the workaround above wouldn't work anyway.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE MyTable ( t TEXT, FULLTEXT INDEX(t));

   SELECT MATCH(t2) AGAINST ('...') FROM (SELECT t AS t2 FROM MyTable) AS d;
   ERROR 1191 (HY000): Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
   ```